# Is there a caption for pre code?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

There's `<caption>` for tables and `<figcaption>` for figures, but what's the correct tag for pre?

(The intention is to have a caption for a [listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listing_(computer)), but it seems `<listing>` has been removed, so `<pre>` is used instead.)

Comment: Why not use <caption> for <pre>?

Comment: @JonasSchafft `<caption>` must be included within a table tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A figure can depict a code listing, so just place the `<pre>` within a `<figure>` and use `<figcaption>` for the caption. The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) contains an example of exactly this:

> This example shows the `figure` element to mark up a code listing.
>
> ```
> <p>In <a href="#l4">listing 4</a> we see the primary core interface
> API declaration.</p>
> <figure id="l4">
>  <figcaption>Listing 4. The primary core interface API declaration.</figcaption>
>  <pre><code>interface PrimaryCore {
>  boolean verifyDataLine();
>  void sendData(in sequence&lt;byte> data);
>  void initSelfDestruct();
> }</code></pre>
> </figure>
> <p>The API is designed to use UTF-8.</p>
> ```

Comment: I've always used figures for graphics only, so this feels wrong... It would also mean that the figure count and listing count are different (14 vs 4 as in the example), which is non-ideal to me. However, I'm accepting your answer as it is technically correct, even if I don't like it.

Comment: @FrankVel: It’s a lower-case L, not a 1 (i.e., `l4`, not `14`).

Comment: @unor haha, that's a terrible font. My point was just that I cannot count the number of figures to tell the number of listings with this solution.